# Spring CSRF: Ajax giving 403 error even after setting request headers

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf

I have set up CSRF authentication using Spring Security 4.0. While using AJAX i am getting 403 error each time. I have set up the request headers.

The meta tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"><head>
<meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

AJAX looks like this:

```
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("th:content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("th:content");



$.ajax({
type : "POST",
url : "/PRIT/Home/PopulateVisits",
async: false,
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
   if (header && token) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
   }
},
.
.
.
```

I can see the request headers in the ajax request :

```
> Accept:*/* Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
> Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9 Cache-Control:no-cache
> Connection:keep-alive Content-Length:9
> Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
> Cookie:JSESSIONID=C3CAAD64269BD0B96FF35B87053B5899 Host:localhost:8082
> Origin:http://localhost:8082 Pragma:no-cache
> Referer:http://localhost:8082/PRIT/Login User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
> X-CSRF-TOKEN:23c07d26-0494-4588-a158-624791258762
> X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest


Request URL:http://localhost:8082/PRIT/Home/PopulateVisits
Request Method:POST
Status Code:403 
Remote Address:[::1]:8082
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

I am not sure what's going wrong. The requested controller is never accessed. The controller is like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Home/PopulateVisits", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody List<DataCollectionForm> PopulateVisits(DataCollectionForm dataCollectionForm, HttpServletRequest request) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue, in my case i was invalidating the spring session during login. Make sure you are not invalidating the Spring session anywhere in your controller prior to the request you are trying to access. Spring associates the token with the session, invalidating it would produce a new token.